# Is it safe? Overwrite apache2 index.php for security

Tags: php, linux, security, http, apache2

I want safe links and hide files from persons who dont know about the exact file. (like a dropbox link to a file)

I have question about security of apache2 related to this:

if i want to have access on files, if i know the filename, but dont want other people to have access via "browsing" this file, is it safe if i create a index.php in every folder without content and set apache2 to show index.php for the default index-page?

if i browse www.mytestpage.com/secretfolder/ i get without the empty index.php a list of all secretfiles12345.zip there. 
if i specify index.php apache2 shows a emtpy page but i can still access mytestpage.com/secretfolder/secretfiles12345.zip .

guarantees this, that only persons who know the exact filename of secretfiles12345.zip has access to the file?

(very sorry for my bad english :) )

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
Options -Indexes
```

in Apache2 configuration to prevent directory listings. You can do this in the global configuration file or in `.htaccess`.

Background: An empty index file (this need not be a php file, it could be a `.html` as well) only prevents access if you access the url without a trailing slash. Then Apache uses the default (`index`). If you have this trailing slash, it assumes that you really want to know what files are in the directory and retrieves the list - if you do not instruct it otherwise (with `Options -Indexes`, see above).